# Cannot open .dat file in c++

Tags: c++

I know there are many posts about `.dat` files.

My problem is I wanted to open a `.dat` file that, I think, contains plain text (I saw it in properties).

So I've made this as I've been doing for open `.txt` files:

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(mypath);

//I also have tried with ios::binary and it doesn't work
//then I check if the file is open
if(!inputFile) { cout<<"something went wrong"<<endl; }
```

The message `something went wrong` appears on my display and I can't read the text inside to parse it later.

Sorry if I'm asking anything too obvious but I'm new working with files and I think I need some help because I have searched in many websites and I haven't found anything that I can understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the file path and working directory of the application. If it didn't solve your problem and you want some help, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Relevant information for this question would include 1) the name and location of the file you are trying to open, 2) the value of `mypath`, and 3) the directory from which the program executes (which might be not what you expect if running from an IDE).

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely no problem with the `.dat` type, as C++ does not distinguish between different file types.

What I can assume, is that you want to open the file in binary mode (`std::ios::binary` as a second argument). But this is true only if your file contains binary data, i.e. non-printable characters.

A possible solution is to give the full path of the file and this way you will be able to tell if the problem is with opening the file or your path.

Debugging method:

1. Throwing `std::system_error` exception. (requires `C++11` and above)

Windows:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <system_error>
try {
    throw std::system_error(static_cast<int>(GetLastError()), std::system_category()););
} catch (std::system_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

Linux:

```
#include <system_error>
#include <cerrno>
try {
    throw std::system_errer(std::system_category(), errno);
} catch (std::system_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

2. Printing the current path of the executable.
   If you have C++17 and above, you can easily check your current path using

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path();
```

Good luck

Comment: You were right and It was an issue with the path. I checked the full path and now everything works fine. Thank you!